# Unable to add an element to "one-to-many" relationship, hibernate.

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, insert-update

I have the following problem: I am not able to add a new `Car` to the corresponding `Customer` entity. The error is the following:

```
Duplicate entry 'test_login' for key 'UK_l4t3rudi0h7ibnjpnbvcnkcbf'
```

where `'test_login'` is the `Customer` login.

Here the code for the `Customer` entity

```
public class Customer{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String login;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Vehicle> vehicles = new  ArrayList<>();

    public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle){
        vehicle.setCustomer(this);
        vehicles.add(vehicle);
    }
 }
```

For `Vehicle` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle")
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "id")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id")
    private Customer customer;
}
```

DAO implementation class:

```
public void addANewVehicle(Vehicle vehicle, Customer customer) {

        customer.addVehicle(vehicle);
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        try {

            session.getTransaction().begin();
            session.save(customer);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
            logger.error("Error occurred while adding a new car. Error stack trace: " + e.toString());
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
```

Comment: save() is used to **insert** a new entity. What you want is to update or merge an existing entity.

Comment: I understad that. And what I just said is that you shouldn't use save(), since save() **inserts** a new customer, and you don't want that. So use update() or merge().

Comment: Ok, I tried to use `update` or  `merge`, but I got the constraint violation error on `vehicle` table. Do you think that the  `addVehicle` is correctly implemented?

Comment: And what's the message and stack trace of "the constraint violation error".

Comment: `a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`vehicle`, CONSTRAINT `FKlwqsusjj6iodeb0df1b554vxq` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`id))`

Comment: Well, it seems you're now updatng a customer with a wrong ID.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column (name = "login", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String login;
```

Field login is set to unique, when save customer without primary key hibernate will create insert statement and Field login will duplicate.

try to load customer and save it

public void addANewVehicle(Vehicle vehicle, Customer customer) {

```
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    try {

        session.getTransaction().begin();
        Customer cust = session.get(Customer.class,customer.getId());
        cust.addVehicle(vehicle);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
        logger.error("Error occurred while adding a new car. Error stack trace: " + e.toString());
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
```